# Should internet forums be treated as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since Quora, Hacker News, Reddit and StackExchange-like sites are on-topic, if I wanted to figure out how to do X on a forum (for example phpBB) is it off-topic?

Does this mean older internet forums are on-topic? Or are they treated as simple websites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see why they wouldn't be on topic.

I assume you're talking as a user here, and not the admin of a forum. Questions from them should be asked on webmasters.

Comment: The [answer in this WebApps SE Meta question](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/903/7584), states that questions about "*Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB*" are not allowed. Is there an exception to the case (like if you're talking as a user, and not as an admin)?